# Open a txt file with texteditor while its already opend by "fopen()" and in use?

Tags: c++

Logger for my program. I saw in another program that it’s somehow possible to open and read a file with text editor while the program is still using it. Seems it just opens a copy for me and continue logging in the background. This kind of log system I need too. But if I use fopen() I only can open and read the file with my text editor if the Programm already closed it with fclose(); This way would work but I think its a very bad solution and also very slow... to open and close the file on every log :S 
Someone knows how the needed log system is working?

P.S. I'm working in VisualStudio 2013 on Windows 8.1

Sry for my bad English :S

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 different problems.

First is writing of logs. In a Windows system, the buffering will cause the data to be actually written to disk :

- if you close the file
- when you have a fair quantity of new data (unsure between several ko and several Mo)
- if you explicitely flush

Unless if you have a high throughput, I would advise to at least flush (if not close) after each write to avoid loosing logs if program crashes. And it also allows you to read the log file in real time.

Second is reading. Vim for example is known to be able to monitor a file that can be modified by an external process. It will open a popup saying that file has been modified and offer to reload it. I do not know what notepad does in same conditions. But :

- it does not have sense unless first problem has gone
- it is not very efficient since you will reload whole file each time

IMHO, you'd better write a custom reader that mimics Linux `tail -f` :

- read (and display) until end of file
- repeteadly read (with a short sleep after an unsuccessful read) to process newly added data

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the text editor you are using. Some will notice edit to the file and ask you if you want to reload a fresh version.

If you work on linux, and you'd like to have an idea of what's happening in real time you could do someting like

```
tail -f <path-to-file>
```

or if the file doesnt yet exist

```
watch -n 0,2 "cat <path-to-file> | tail"
```

which will display the content of the file and refresh it every 0.2 sec

Comment: Hmm the file even not exists until i did fclose() :S so i cant open it. I use msnotepad.exe. if i use setbuf(pFile, NULL); then it creats the file but its always empty until program clsoed it with fclose() :S

Answer (score 0):

Thx for your fast answers :)
Crazy.. i was working so long with fopen() and found no solution.. also the fflush(pFile) didnt help (I wasnt able to open file.. always error that its already in use by another program). I never tryed the fstream. Seems fstream solved my problem now. I can open my file with msnotepad.exe while the program is still writing to the file :) Here a small test-code:

```
#include <fstream> #include <iostream> using namespace std;
int main(){
ofstream FILE;
FILE.open("E:\\Log.txt");
for (size_t i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    FILE << "Hello " << i << endl;
    cout << "log" << endl;
    _sleep(500);        
}   
FILE.close();
cout << "finish" << endl;
return 0;}
```

Comment: The underlying reason for you error is in the sharing mode of the file that - it's surprising to me too - is differently handled by the two APIs. The flag responsible for this in the underlying windows API is dwShareMode, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx. In order to be able to open the file with a log viewer (I suggest to give a try to baretail) or an editor, while it's opened by your program, it must be set to FILE_SHARE_READ.